# Getting full coordinates of the argmax of an array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization, indexing

I have a multi-dimensional maximization problem. There are (let's say) one state and two control variables (`x1` and `x2`,`x3` respectively): for each value of the state variable `x1`, we maximize some objective function by varying `x2` and `x3`.

In Matlab, then, I have a 3-dimensional array, let's call it `F`, with `x1` in the first dimension and (`x2`,`x3`) in the latter dimensions.

Getting the max is easy--just set:
`F_star=max(max(F,[],2),[],3)`;
This returns the length-N_1 vector of maxima for each `x1`.

My problem is with getting the indices / coordinates of the maximizer(s).

My first guess was to use the extended function call:

`[F_star, maximizers]=max(max(F,[],2),[],3);`

However, this only operates on the OUTERMOST `max` function, and so will only return the maximizing index in the 3rd dimension.

One could, of course, just repeat this and permute the dimensions:

`[F_star, maximizers_3]=max(max(F,[],2),[],3);`

`[F_star, maximizers_2]=max(max(F,[],3),[],2);`

But it hardly seems efficient to take the max twice (which is important for my actual problem because there are actually 3 control variables and 7 state variables, so it is quite a burden to search over my whole array).

Any ideas for a simpler way to extract all of the coordinates or indices?

For concreteness, here's a simple example:

```
F = 10*rand(2,2,2)

[y, z3] = max(max(F,[],2),[],3)

[y, z2] = max(max(F,[],3),[],2)

F(:,:,1) =

    2.1203    9.1380

    0.7735    7.0672


F(:,:,2) =

    5.5779    1.6620

    3.1343    6.2250


y =

    9.1380

    7.0672


z3 =

     1

     1


y =

    9.1380

    7.0672


z2 =

     2

     2
```

By combining `z2` & `z3`, we get what we want:
The max when at the first value of `x1` (i.e., in `F(1,:,:)`) is 9.1, which happens at `(z2(1),z3(1)) -- F(1,z2(1),z3(1))=F(1,2,1)`

The max when at the first value of `x2` (i.e., in `F(2,:,:)`) is 7.1, which happens at `(z2(2),z3(2)) -- F(1,z2(2),z3(2))=F(2,2,1)`

It would be awesome to have something like:
`[F_star, z2, z3] = max(F,[2 3])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Linearize" (combine) 2nd and 3rd dimensions with [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html); get the linear index of the maximizers along the combined dimensions; and convert to two subindices with [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html):

```
[F_star ind] = max(reshape(F, size(F,1), []), [], 2);
[z2 z3] = ind2sub([size(F,2) size(F,3)], ind);
```

That will give you the maximum (`F_star`) and its position in 2nd and 3rd dimensions (`z2`,  `z3`), for each 1st-dimension slice.

---

For more than three dimensions, if you want to maximize for each 1st-dimension slice, the generalization is easy:

```
s = size(F);
[F_star ind] = max(reshape(F, s(1), []), [], 2);
z = cell(1,numel(s)-1);
[z{:}] = ind2sub(s(2:end), ind);
```

The position is given in a cell array `z`, such that `z{1}` is your `z2`, `z{2}` is your `z3` etc.

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines! I'll follow up if it turns out I oversimplified by cutting out the other 7 dimensions. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelChirico See edited answer (last part) for an arbitrary number of dimensions

Comment: the extension is a bit more tricky than that--I have 7 state dimensions (not 1 as in the simple example) and 3 choice dimensions. So this generalizes to:
s = size(F);
[F_star ind] = max(reshape(F, [s(1:n) []]), [], 2);
z = cell(1,numel(s)-n);
[z{:}] = ind2sub(s((n+1):end), ind);
where n is the number of state dimensions.
Thanks!

Comment: Actually the syntax [s(1:n) []] didn't seem to work.
Instead: [s(1:n) prod(s((n+1):end))]

Comment: @MichaelChirico That's true. `[]` in `reshape` can be used with a list: `reshape(F, s(1), s(2), s(3), [])`.  But not with a vector: `reshape(F, s(1:n), [])` is not allowed